# Measure time spent by a user during a website visit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, timer

I'm trying to build a website locally using PHP and Javascript and MAMP.

What I'm looking for is to put a timer on every page of the website and that timer counts the time spent by the user in the whole website. Even if the user switches between pages the timer will still continue. The solution I've found only shows the time spent on each page and when I reload the same page again the timer restart from zero.

Here's the Javascript for the timer I did:

```
window.onload=function(){
 time=0;
}
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
 timeSite = new Date()-time;
 window.localStorage['timeSite']=timeSite;
}
```

I've search everywhere for the solution but with no luck, if anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Use a session variable, it will be shared by all the pages.

Comment: on pure javascript solution try the updated answer... coffee worked well i think... additionally @Barmar has a point there. meaning that in your case i would try to write something similar server-side based on session var just in case javascript is disabled in browser. (how often is that!!!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a working example. It will stop counting when the user closes the window/tab.

```
var timer;
var timerStart;
var timeSpentOnSite = getTimeSpentOnSite();

function getTimeSpentOnSite(){
    timeSpentOnSite = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timeSpentOnSite'));
    timeSpentOnSite = isNaN(timeSpentOnSite) ? 0 : timeSpentOnSite;
    return timeSpentOnSite;
}

function startCounting(){
    timerStart = Date.now();
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        timeSpentOnSite = getTimeSpentOnSite()+(Date.now()-timerStart);
        localStorage.setItem('timeSpentOnSite',timeSpentOnSite);
        timerStart = parseInt(Date.now());
        // Convert to seconds
        console.log(parseInt(timeSpentOnSite/1000));
    },1000);
}
startCounting();
```

Add the code below if you want to stop the timer when the window/tab is inactive:

```
var stopCountingWhenWindowIsInactive = true; 

if( stopCountingWhenWindowIsInactive ){

    if( typeof document.hidden !== "undefined" ){
        var hidden = "hidden", 
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange", 
        visibilityState = "visibilityState";
    }else if ( typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined" ){
        var hidden = "msHidden", 
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange", 
        visibilityState = "msVisibilityState";
    }
    var documentIsHidden = document[hidden];

    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
        if(documentIsHidden != document[hidden]) {
            if( document[hidden] ){
                // Window is inactive
                clearInterval(timer);
            }else{
                // Window is active
                startCounting();
            }
            documentIsHidden = document[hidden];
        }
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e223aht/44/)

Comment: If i visit the https://jsfiddle.net/4e223aht/44/ example i see the console writing the counting seconds. I close the window. I re-visit the example page on jsfiddle  and see the console counting from the time of the last visit. Is this correct? Shouldn't it be counting all over again from start on re-visit?

Comment: That's the correct behavior. It does exactly what OP asked for: Count the time spent by the user in the ***whole website***, even if the user ***switches between pages***.

Comment: *switches between pages*... doesn't it mean, to count correctly the time on website even if the user open two or three browser windows of the same website and get the same time on each window? But if a user closes the browser and all windows relevant to that webpage, should the script re-count the time on a new visit?

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to do in this question is to determine the *per visit* user-time. The term *per visit* means that if the user opens 4 windows of the same page not to count from start user-time on each new window. I think that is the title `Measure time spent by a user during a website visit` and i also think that in your way you count total time spent in all user visits in a website. This happens because you don't clear `localStorage` so if i re-visit the website the time starts counting using the previous spent time on website.

Answer (score 3):

Using `localStorage` may not be the best choice for what you need. But `sessionStorage`, and `localStorage` is most suitable. Have in mind that `sessionStorage` when opening a new tab resolves to a new session, so using `localStorage` has to do with the fact that if only `sessionStorage` was used and a user opened a new tab in parallel and visit your website would resolve to a new separate session for that browser tab and would count `timeOnSite` from start for it. In the following example it is tried for this to be avoid and count the exact `timeOnSite`.

> The `sessionStorage` property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object for the current origin. `sessionStorage` is similar to
>   `Window.localStorage`, the only difference is while data stored in
>   `localStorage` has no expiration set, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets
>   cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long
>   as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores.
>   Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be
>   initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

```
function myTimer() {
if(!sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisitTime')) {
   var myDate = Date.now();
   if(!localStorage.getItem('timeOnSite')) {
   sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisitTime',myDate);
   } else {
   if(localStorage.getItem('tabsCount') && parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tabsCount'))>1){
   sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisitTime',myDate-parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timeOnSite'))); 
   } else {
   sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisitTime',myDate);
   } 
}
}
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){  
   var time = Date.now()-parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisitTime'));
   localStorage.setItem('timeOnSite',time); 
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (time/1000)+' seconds have passed since first visit';
}, 1000);
return myInterval;
}    
window.onbeforeunload=function() {
console.log('Document onbeforeunload state.');
clearInterval(timer);
};
window.onunload=function() {
var time = Date.now();
localStorage.setItem('timeLeftSite',time);
localStorage.setItem("tabsCount",parseInt(localStorage.getItem("tabsCount"))-1);
console.log('Document onunload state.');
};
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
if(localStorage.getItem("tabsCount")){
localStorage.setItem("tabsCount",parseInt(localStorage.getItem("tabsCount"))+1);
var timer = myTimer();
} else {
localStorage.setItem("tabsCount",1);
}
   console.log("Document complete state.");
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e223aht/74/)

If you want a server-side solution then set a `$_SESSION['timeOnSite']` variable and update accordingly on each page navigation.

Comment: Your solution doesn't give the time spent by the user on the website. It only returns the elapsed time since the first visit.

Comment: @EtienneMartin.... if you mean that it keeps the localStorage key `firstVisitTime` even if you close the browser, and that in your next visit it starts counting from that date and not the new `firstVisitTime`, then i will try to edit accordingly, once i drink some...coffee! :)

Comment: @EtienneMartin `sessionStorage` seems to be the best choice for this question. In case you would not want to have a problem in counting spent time in website. The only issue is that on new browser tab on same page time counts for that user session alone.

Comment: @EtienneMartin i will edit my answer it seems that using `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` and a `setInterval` does the work. Counts correctly the time a user spent on site even if 2-3 tabs are open but when user closes all tabs and re-opens, new session starts.

Comment: i could never understood someone down-voting something that works fine. My answer shows the time spent by the user on the website. It will count time correctly for as long one or more browser tabs are open visiting various pages from a single website. When all browser tabs are closed time spent on website will be reset to zero until the next visit.